# C++ and OpenGL Help

Tags: c++, opengl

I am wanting to code something with OpenGL, but I don't want to have to go through Windows API, is this Possible? If so then some links to tutorials on how to do this would be nice.

Comment: Just keep in mind that graphics processing is very tied to hardware and platform. Anything you use is going to abstract that away from you (perhaps by going through the Windows API, when on Windows, or another API on other OS's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

- [GLFW](http://glfw.sourceforge.net/)
- [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) + [OpenGL](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-index.html)
- [GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) or [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)

Or see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252680/opengl-windowing-library-for-2009).

Comment: @Anthoni: That's why I didn't recommend it :) I'm personally not very fond of it. Anywho, see the "my question" link...that lists all of the one's I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a Win32 window for displaying OpenGL content - without going through Win32 API, GLUT is the only option that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a complete visualization framework, then [VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) is the best FREE choice.